# getJson return values into textboxes

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to take the Json response and get into about 30 individual textboxes.  What happens is when a user lands on the order page there are about 30 textboxes that need to be filled in with information about the product they are purchasing.  If the user has ordered similar items in the past they can click a Reference button.  This button uses getJSON to call the method that populates the object properties to be returned.  Here is the code below.   We are using MVC3.

```
 $("#btnRefJob").click(function (e) {
           //alert("Hi button"); 
           var rjobvalue = $("#RefJob").val();
           var rjdata;
           $.getJSON("/KKOrder/GetRefJob", { refNum: rjobvalue }, function (rjdata) {
            //alert("Shallow");
            $.each(rjdata, function (i, item) {
                alert(rjdata[i].Code1);
            });

        });
    });
```

Comment: So the text boxes already exist on the page? How does the data received relate to the text boxes?

Comment: Can you specify how are you identifing which data fills which text box?

Comment: the textboxes already exist on the page. The button click causes the ORDER object's properties to be populated with values. I need to get the specific values into the specific textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty hard to tell without seing the HTML and JSON data structure. But I would to something like this:

```
$.each(rjdata, function (i, item) {
    $('#' + item.Id).val(item.Code1);
});
```

This requires the HTML markup to have textboxes with matching id:s for each `rjdata` id. But you get the idea.

Comment: Here's a sample of the HTML markup. <tr>
                            <td width="90">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PONum)
                            </td>
                            <td width="210">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PONum, new { style = "width:80px;" })

Comment: that... isn't html markup. that's some kind of server-side language code. relatively useless for debugging javascript.

Comment: keep in mind we are using MVC3.  The sample presented is the code on the view that creates the textboxes.